# Log parsed request with nginx

Tags: logging, nginx, url-rewriting

How to set a custom log format for nginx, so that request got parsed and its parts are logged separate?

We serve a picture file to count mail opens. The url to the picture varies, but follows the rule:

```
http://www.server.com/counter/XXXXX/YYYYY/dailymail.gif
```

XXXXX - id of email campaign;
YYYYY - recipient id.

There's a separate log for `/counter` location, which I'd like to give a format like

```
XXXXX   YYYYY    DATETIME
```

Location section looks like

```
    location    ~* ^counter/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/dailymail\.gif$ {
        access_log /var/log/mailopened.log
        alias /var/www/site.com/1x1.gif?cid=$1&uid=$2&type=daily;
    }
```

So I have the values in variables $1 and $2. How can I use them in the log format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`log_format` directive is allowed at `http` level only, so you have to define it in terms of other variables, e.g.

```
http {
  log_format tracking "$xxxx $yyyy $time_local";
```

Later, in your location, just set these variables and log in `tracking` format:

```
location ~* ^counter/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/dailymail\.gif$ {
  set $xxxx $1;
  set $yyyy $2;
  access_log /var/log/mailopened.log tracking;
  alias /var/www/site.com/1x1.gif?cid=$1&uid=$2&type=daily;
}
```

With recent versions of Nginx and PCRE library it's possible to omit `set` calls and name the captures explicitly in `location` (thanks to @kolbyjack):

```
location ~* ^counter/(?<xxxx>[0-9]+)/(?<yyyy>[^/]+)/dailymail\.gif$ {
  access_log /var/log/mailopened.log tracking;
  alias /var/www/site.com/1x1.gif?cid=$1&uid=$2&type=daily;
}
```

Comment: With any recent version of nginx, you can name the captures and skip the set calls using `location ~* ^/counter/(?<xxxx>[0-9]+)/(?<yyyy>[^/]+)/dailymail.gif$ {`

Comment: Good catch! PCRE version is relevant too -- you may have latest Nginx and old PCRE..

Comment: Good point.  With an old pcre, you'd need to use `?P<` instead of just `?<`