# conditionally logging $request_body based on location in nginx config

Tags: nginx

I need to configure Nginx to log the `$request_body` only for certain `location` blocks.

Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041271/log-parsed-request-with-nginx), I expected the following to work:

```
http {

    log_format l2met "request_body = $xxxx";
    access_log logs/nginx/access.log l2met;
    error_log logs/nginx/error.log;

    server {

        location /path/to/log {
            set $xxxx $request_body;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
        }

        location / {
            set $xxxx "NOT_LOGGED";
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the request body just gets printed as `-`

I can print the `$request_body` all the time with this:

```
http {

    log_format l2met "request_body = $request_body";
    access_log logs/nginx/access.log l2met;
    error_log logs/nginx/error.log;

    server {

        location /path/to/log {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
        }
    }
}
```

I can conditionally set the logging with this:

```
http {

    log_format l2met "xxxx = $xxxx";
    access_log logs/nginx/access.log l2met;
    error_log logs/nginx/error.log;

    server {

        location /path/to/log {
            set $xxxx "NEED TO LOG REQUEST BODY HERE";
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
        }

        location / {
            set $xxxx "NOT_LOGGED";
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, it seems that as soon as I reference `$request_body` from inside a `location` block, the log output changes to `-`.

I've tried adding `client_body_in_single_buffer` to the `http` block, but that doesn't seem to help.

How do I make this work?

I'm using the version of nginx that was installed by default with `apt-get`:

```
$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.1.19
```

Comment: Why you not just put `access_log` into `location` where you need to log body?

Comment: @AlexeyTen My understanding is that `access_log` just changes where the logs are written. Are you suggesting that I disable logging for all other locations, and then only log for the 1 location I need the body? Kind of a bummer to lose logging everywhere else. What I really want to do is change `log_format` in that `location`, but `log_format` is only allowed in `http`

Comment: You define log format in http, but could use it anywhere

Comment: @AlexeyTen I didn't realize you could declare multiple `log_format` declarations in `http`. That works great! My final result looked something like this: https://gist.github.com/jefflab/01f592a4c4754433d65d. If you want to post that as the answer, I will accept.

Comment: OK. BTW, you don't need `set $xxxx ...` anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare any number of `log_format`s and use ones that you need.

```
http {
  log_format l2met 'measure#nginx.service=$request_time request_id=$http_x_request_id';
  log_format capturebody "request_body = $request_body";
  access_log logs/nginx/access.log l2met;

  server {
    ...
    location / {
      ...
    }
    location /other/ {
      # this is the location where you need to log $request_body
      access_log logs/nginx/access.log capturebody;
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```